# JPOS remove zero padding IFB_NUMERIC

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

the problem is in the fourth field (and maybe 11):
`<field id="4" value="000000010000"/>`

it should be:

`<field id="4" value="10000"/>`

I used IFB_NUMERIC isoFieldPackager for this field. Does correct isofieldpackager exist for my case? Or I need to some other decision...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jPOS doesn't perform content manipulation like unpadding. The packager just put what it reads and is the responsibility of the higher-level logic to make the unpadding.

You can use `ISOUtil.zeroUnpad(m.getString(4))` method for that.